# How to use a folder in Yahoo mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

When I created a folder in my Yahoo mail

1. is there any way to save mails from a particular address in that folder automatically?
2. and is there any way to encrypt a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo mail is protected with **username and password** and this is the primary security for your files and there in **no way to encrypt the folder** within your yahoo mail.

**Follow the below procedure to send the mails from particular address to your desired folder**

- Select Options | Mail Options from the toolbar.
- Go to the Filters category.
- Click the + Add button.
- Type the sender's name under Filter Name:.
- Enter the desired sender's email address under Sender: Contains.
- Make sure sender match case is not checked.
- Under Then deliver the email to the following folder, select the
  desired target folder from the drop-down menu.
- If you have not yet created a folder for the contact, select [New
  Folder], Type the new folder's name under Folder name and click OK.
- Click Save.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir thank you for your help but I found that Filter category in settings.